# Improving performance with a Crystal Report containing a subreport?

Tags: performance, ado.net, crystal-reports

Does anybody know how to improve the performance of a Crystal Report that has a subreport?  The subreport uses ADO.NET objects...and takes FOREVER to generate.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't the query that it is calling?

Comment: Is it possible to avoid the subreport? If you can get the same result by applying group bands to a resultset from a single query, ths may drastcally improve performance.

Comment: I'm positive it's the subreport that's affecting the performance--it's when my program sets the report to the viewer where the problems arise with performance.

I can't avoid the subreport--it's a req in my project :(

Answer (score 0):

Is the subreport being called for every record of your report, ie does it live in the details section? If so, there's not much you can do other than reduce what the report displays or calculates. Subreports in details sections are a blight on performance.
However, if it's elsewhere then optimizations would necessarily depend on the design of the subreport itself. For example, running totals or the use of distinct counts can hit performance depending on design or report size.